CFMessagePortSendRequest FAILED(-1)
I'm using PyQT6 on MacOS and exec() to open dialog
if dialog.exec() == QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted:
    print("Adding...")
else:
    print("Adding cancelled")

The reason for exec is to block the execution until I get result from the dialog. However, often I am getting the following lines

TSMSendMessageToUIServer: CFMessagePortSendRequest FAILED(-1) to send
to port com.apple.tsm.uiserver

What this error means and how to solve it?

Is it an error or just a warning? You might try setting export QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1 before executing your script and see if that helps.

@l'L'l In the terminal it's shown in red color. I don't really know if it's error or warning. But I would like to understand before giving my script to production. Your setting brought the following: qt.qpa.drawing: Layer-backing is always enabled.  QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER/_q_mac_wantsLayer has no effect.
